# SQL Anywhere 11 - Check if event exists

Tags: sql, schedule, sqlanywhere

I have an SQL script which creates a scheduled event:

```
CREATE EVENT "Daily_1200PM"
SCHEDULE "Daily_1200PM" START TIME '12:00' EVERY 24 HOURS
HANDLER
begin 
   -- Blah blah, do some stuff here
end;
```

I would like to remove this event, if it exists. I know I can remove the event with the following:

```
DROP EVENT "Daily_1200PM"
```

But for some databases, the the event doesn't actually exist, so an error is thrown.

How do I delete the event *only* if it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if exists( select * from sys.sysevent where event_name='Daily_1200PM' ) then
    drop event Daily_1200PM;
end if
```