# How to check the file path exists in sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

How to check the `filename` exists in `sybase Sql Anywhere11` and return error message if not in `Sql Anywhere11`?

I have a `textbox` and `submit` button in front end. So the user can enter the `file path` into the `textbox` and click `submit`.

The `submit` button call the `procedure` and i want to check in the beginning of the procedure weather the `file exists` or not and `return` some `value` if not exists.

### Example:

`D:/hello/world.csv` is the `path` name.

So I need to check the `D:/hello` is a valid path and `world.csv` is exist in the specified path.

Thanks

Comment: Again Updated the question. Sorry. @michaelgardner

Comment: Those checks would likely be handled by your application, not the database.  The database is there primarily to store/retreive data.  The application is there to handle business logic, and interact with the Operating System.  The database can check to see if those values are already stored, but won't validate that the values are valid.  Here's an example of an existance check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263680/sql-anywhere-11-check-if-event-exists

Comment: If you do want the database to handle those checks, you will likely have to use `xp_cmdshell`(http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.0/dbreference_en11/sysproc-s-4380894.html), which will allow you to call OS commands from within the database.  Those OS commands could be used to validate the path/filename.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael. I added the checking condition in application and it seems to be working fine. Thanks @michaelgardner